# Displaying special characters in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown, special-characters

I am trying to write a scientific article using Jupyter Notebook and I am having issues with displaying some characters, such as CO2, which will be shown in this way:

[image: Screenshot of the incorrect layout]

I tried to follow the documentation of Jupyter Notebook for showing formulas and special characters.

This how I've written it:

```
The NEE decreased significantly with increasing catch crop diversity (Fig. 1), suggesting increasing $$CO_2$$-C uptake from the atmosphere.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [the subscript 2 symbol (₂)](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2082) inside your text, like this:

```
[…] suggesting increasing CO₂-C uptake from the atmosphere.
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use [latex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) $CO_2$ or $\text{CO}_2$ in a markdown cell