# I paste code in a jupyter notebook. The hidden characters from text editor are copied. How to disable this?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, special-characters, hidden-characters

I am using Jupyter Notebook with the Python 3 ipykernel. If I paste code from a text editor into the Jupyter Notebook, all the hidden characters (in the text editor) show up as visible characters.
It is strange: e.g., I can backspace and erase the space hidden character, then hit space and it does not reappear.

What is happening and how do I disable it?

I tried to paste the character here, but they disappear. Here is an image for reference:
[image]

To resolve this issue, I use `crtl+a`, `tab`, `shift+tab`, and the hidden characters disappear. I am use Sublime 3 as a text editor, but if I open gedit, and I type exactly what is displayed in the image and paste in Jupyter Notebooks, I still see the hidden characters. This issue is new (e.g., it wasn't occurring just a week ago).

Comment: While we typically discourage images of code or other textual data, this seems like a case where a screenshot would be very helpful.

Comment: Kindly paste (image) screenshot as @CrazyChucky indicated. Kindly write ✍️ snippet of your corrected code. Here's an example of a [question with screenshot and code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64701552/displaying-special-characters-in-jupyter-notebook). Would be great if you indicate the text editor.

Comment: I added an image to the question, and I added info on the text editor. Surprisingly, I am seeing the issue regardless of the text editor.

Answer (score 3):

> I am use Sublime 3 as a text editor

Your complaint boils down to "my text editor is indenting with TAB character rather than with four SPACE characters".

You can verify that diagnosis with `tail my_source_code.py | hexdump -C`
and notice the `0x09` (decimal nine) TAB characters instead
of `0x20` (decimal 32) SPACE characters.

---

Visit the Preferences screen in your editor
and ask it to use SPACE instead of TAB.